# Search wordpress for outdated html buttons

Tags: wordpress

I have hundreds of posts on my wordpress site, many of which contain outdated ejunkie buttons I added with html code. How can I search my wordpress site for this html so I can remove the outdated button code?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an similar Question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/188384/how-to-mass-delete-one-line-from-all-posts

The answer should be suitable for your problem.

Comment: If you want to post this as an answer, it would be preferred to add the contents to your answer instead of just linking. If you want to just link, either post it as a comment or vote as duplicate.